# Unable send correct data from UICollectionView Embedded inside UITableView to ViewController Swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I am using a UICollectionView Embedded inside UITableView. I am playing music when user tap on UICollectionViewCell which is inside UITableView but when UITableView is loaded first time the data var is nil, when user tap on UICollectionViewCell the nil value is passed. when when user again tap on UICollectionViewCell than it is showing actual value of that UICollectionViewCell.

Here is my code:

//UITableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell {

 @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var vcInstance: newHomeTableViewController?
var parentViewController: UIViewController? = nil


 var didSelectAction: (() -> Void )?

 }

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegate{

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return imageurl.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "newHomeCell1", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

     cell.image1.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageurl[indexPath.row]))

    return cell

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //print("cell no: \(indexPath.row) of collection view: \(collectionView.tag)")

    didSelectAction!()

     vcInstance?.musicName = RemoteModel.sharedInstanceRemoteModel.singleGuidedTrandingTrackname[indexPath.row]
     vcInstance?.musicUrl = RemoteModel.sharedInstanceRemoteModel.singleGuidedTrandingTrackurl[indexPath.row]

    }

   }

   extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let _: CGFloat = 10
    return CGSize(width : (collectionView.bounds.width)/2 - 10, height : collectionView.bounds.height - 10)
   }

  }
```

// TableViewController:-

```
import UIKit

class newTableViewController: UITableViewController {

 var musicName : String?
 var musicUrl : String?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{

    return 70
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

         let cell : CategoryRow = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")as! CategoryRow

        cell.vcInstance = self
         cell.parentViewController = self

         cell.didSelectAction = {
             self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "homePlayer", sender: indexPath)
         }

        return cell
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "homePlayer" {

        let playerVC = segue.destination as! playerViewController

        playerVC.UrlAudio = musicUrl
        playerVC.songTittle = musicName

       }
    }

  }
```

This is working well except when first time UITableView is loaded, the data var is nil.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please somebody help me..

Answer (score 1):

kindly refer to the code below, i have created a demo for you, matching your requirement, hope it helps!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


     @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
     @IBOutlet weak var outputLbl: UILabel!

     var content = ["Good Morning1","Good Morning2","Good Morning3","Good Morning4","Good Morning5"]

     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          tblView.rowHeight = 400
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return 01
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath ) as! aTableViewCell
          cell.aCollection.reloadData()
          return cell
     }
}

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return content.count
     }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! ACollectionViewCell
          cell.aLabel.text = content[indexPath.item]
          return cell
     }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          let collectionCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ACollectionViewCell
          let selectedData = collectionCell.aLabel.text
          outputLbl.text = selectedData
     }

}

class aTableViewCell : UITableViewCell{

     @IBOutlet weak var aCollection: UICollectionView!
}
```

Comment: I think delegate and datasource of collection view should assign programmatically in tableview's cellForRowAtIndexpath instead of connecting within xib & after that reload the collection view in same method.

Comment: outputLbl is the label i took on my ViewController, to represent the selected data from the embedded collectionViewCell.

Comment: Should i implement delegate and data source method of collectionviewcell in tableview instead of tableviewcell?

Comment: where did you set your delegate and datasource of your collectionView?

Comment: in mycode i have set the collectionView's delegate and datasource from the storyboard to the viewController itself, so i implemented my methods in ViewController. If you too have done same, then you also have to implement the methods in ViewController

Comment: Buddy i'm implement this inside UITableviewcontroller, and i've implement delegate and datasource of collectionView inside UITableViewCell.

Comment: write the delegate and datasource method in UITableViewController class.

Comment: I tried it, but doesn't happened except NSException Error. My data is passing successfully, the problem is first time tableview is loaded data is nil,.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162401/discussion-between-chetan-lodhi-and-madhur-diwan).

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, for the very first time, the values are `nil`, to avoid this, you must reload your `UICollectionViewCell` which is embedded in the `UITableViewCell`,

So to reload `UICollectionViewCell`, in tableView's `cellForRowAt:` write,

```
yourCollectionView.reloadData()
```

which should make your code work!

Comment: i tried this one, as you said :- cell.collectionView.reloadData().. Error occurred in tableView's cellForRowAt.

Comment: Nothing, only lldb came n crashed.

Comment: It shouldn't crash, clean your code and run again to see.

Comment: Shouldn't it be collectionView.reloadData() , you are calling cell.collectionView.reloadData(). Try replacing .

Comment: cell.collectionView.reloadData() is fine, as the collectionView is embedded in tableView

Comment: @ChetanLodhi, hi, kindly confirm me one thing, the view hierarchy is as follows: ViewController -> TableView -> TableViewCell -> CollectionView -> CollectionViewCell,
and you want the selected data from CollectionViewCell to present at ViewController , ryt??

Comment: Ya right. and hierarchy is TableViewController -> TableViewCell -> CollectionView -> CollectionViewCell